# Ant for other ant's

Tags: ant, build-process

I have several projects, most of them has "*test*" target, which run tests and store results in property '*test.faulire*'.

All projects located in same directory:

- big_project / someproject1
- big_project / someproject1 / build.xml
- big_project / someproject2
- big_project / someproject2 / build.xml

So, in root of 'big_project' i want to create one *build.xml* for:

1. Running test on all projects
2. If *all* test ok, run "*deploy*" task on each project. It'll be very well
   if I could pass some deployment
   parameters to each project.

How would you realize this scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a look at the *for* task in [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/). With it you could iterate over all directories like that:

```
<for param="dir">
  <path>
    <dirset dir="." includes="*"/>
  </path>
  <sequential>
    <ant dir="${dir}" antfile="${dir}/build.xml" target="aTarget" />
  </sequential>
</for>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Ant [manual page on the 'subant' task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html). The page  contains examples on how to use the task the way you want to.