# Create an ant file to run other ant files

Tags: ant

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108862/ant-for-other-ants) relevant question but my situation is different so asking this again. Basically, I have 12 ant files that I have to run in a specific sequence. For each ant file, I select a different target, such as "create" or "build and deploy all." How can I create an ant file that will call of the right targets for all of these files?

```
Pseudocode:

<Call antFile1, "clean">
<Call antFile1, "create">
<Call antFile2, "build">
        .
        .
        .
<Call antfile12, "build and deploy all">
```

Comment: When an ant script calls an other one is the place where you should not use ant anymore in my opinion.

Comment: Is there another alternative?

Comment: You should use something standard for managing your project lifecycle like Maven. If you do not have complicated stuff, you will be happy with it without deep learning. If you tell more about your projects, and about what your ant script actually do we could help more.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Maybe have a target like below in encompassing ant file:

```
<target name="all">
     <ant antfile="antFile1" target="clean" />
     <ant antfile="antFile2" target="create" />
     ...
</target>
```

Refer here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html

Comment: Remember to set inheritAll to false, if you want a basedir that is relative to your build.xml-parent-folder !

Answer (score 8):

You can also have import tags:

```
<import file="my_ant_file.xml">
```

And then you can call the ant targets in that file. You may want to qualify (add a prefix to) your target names to avoid ambiguity if you do that.

**EDIT:** Calling the ant targets from the imported file is exactly the same as calling local targets:

```
<antcall target="my_local_target">
<antcall target="my_target_from_an_imported_file">
```

You can also use them as dependencies:

```
<target name="my_target" depends="my_target_from_an_imported_file">
```

Think of it the same way as importing in any programming language. Once it's imported you can use it as-if it were just another target in your file.

Here is the [import documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html).

Comment: Once I have imported all the files, how can I call their targets? Could you give me an example of the syntax?

Comment: Well the problem is that when I call other ant files form a certain folder, instead of following their own properties files, the ant files cannot find the path variables since the master_ant_file (the one that I am creating) does not store the path variables (since each ant build has different path variables). If I put in the path variables of the first ant I call in the properties file of the maser_ant_file, the first build executes fine but the second one cannot find its paths. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I can answer that one. You might want to ask a second question about that, I'm sure someone else here can help you with it.