# ant file that depends on another ant file

Tags: ant

I have two projects, each with its own ant build file.

What should I do so that, when I build project B, it will first build project A using project A's antfile?

Comment: are you looking for [this](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html)?

Comment: Ah, yes, I didn't know about this task type, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create an ant file to run other ant files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335971/create-an-ant-file-to-run-other-ant-files)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the [ant task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html), which runs ant on an external buildfile.

Example:

```
<ant antfile="../otherproject/build.xml" target="compile"/>
```

**Properties**
By default all current properties are passed to the invoked ant build, this can be disabled by setting `inheritAll="false"`, if you want the other build to behave natively.

Properties that are need can be passed by nested  tags:

```
<ant inheritAll="false" antfile="../otherproject/build.xml" target="compile">
  <property name="my.property" value="myValue"/>
</ant>
```

Comment: I had to add another option in order to make the other task work in its own path:

    <ant inheritAll="false" antfile="../otherproject/build.xml" />

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi thanks for the feedback, I worked this into the answer

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but I'm seeing a lot of `Trying to override old definition of task...` warnings. Any way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Where to put the `<ant antfile>` block, inside of `<target>`?