# Can an Ant task execute tasks from other build scripts without importing?

Tags: ant, build, build-automation

I have a number of projects, each of which has their own Ant script that provides targets such as "build", "run", "test" and so on.  Is it possible to write an Ant script for a "top level" project that will chain the appropriate tasks from other scripts, of the form:

```
<target name="test">
    <antcall target="subproject A's test"/>
    <antcall target="subproject B's test"/>
</target>
```

Note that I can't do this just by importing A and B's build.xml at the top of the "top level" build.xml as they would have conflicting target names.

Is there a way to do this within Ant, or would I have to either (a) rename all the targets in the subprojects so that I *can* import them, or (b) write a shell script to run Ant multiple times?

I am using Ant 1.8.2 from within NetBeans 7.0.

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514378/ant-file-that-depends-on-another-ant-file/9515284#9515284. the task is called ant, and it is impossible to google :D

Comment: @oers Yep, that looks about right, thanks!  It seems to have confounded Stack Overflow's search as well as Google :)

Comment: You could look into Maven as well, for single projects I usually prefer Ant as it is a loot simpler but when I have multiple dependent projects Maven helps.