# Generic Ant task to call generic build.xml for all projects into eclipse workpsace

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I'd like to create a generic [ant task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) to call as many projects with "build.xml" exists in my Eclipse workspace.

So far a code a solution where I have to duplicate the code for every project:

```
<project name="AllProjects" default="AllPrjs" basedir=".">
  <!-- Eclipse workspace path considering this file is under a project root -->
  <property name="workspace.path" location="${basedir}\.." />

  <!-- Fixed project names [ProjectA..Z] -->
  <property name="projectB"     value="ServeletAppCustomer" />
  <property name="projectA"     value="ServeletAppStore" />

  <target name="AllPrjs" >

    <!-- Fixed project name and path for [project A] -->
    <property name="projectA.path" location="${workspace.path}\${projectA}\" />
    <ant antfile="${projectA.path}\build.xml" inheritAll="false" target="All" />

    <!-- Fixed project name and path for [project B] -->
    <property name="projectB.path" location="${workspace.path}\${projectB}\" />
    <ant antfile="${projectB.path}\build.xml" inheritAll="false" target="All" />

  </target>
</project>
```

My workspace and build.xml are structured as usual:

```
\workspace
|---> ProjectA\build.xml
|---> ProjectB\build.xml
```

I found a similar answer [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108862/ant-for-other-ants); however, I would like to go for [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) as suggested.

Thanks

Comment: This works without ant-contrib with the built-in [_subant_](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) task instead of the _ant_ task.

Comment: Thanks @howlger, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in **[*subant*](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html)** task instead of the *ant* task and *ant-contrib* for that. Subant can be used in two ways: to run the same build file in different directories or - as in your case - for multiple build files.

```
<subant target="All">
    <fileset dir="${workspace.path}" includes="*/build.xml"/>
</subant>
```